# how move a single div offscreen

Tags: css, html, move, off-screen

i have 2 overlapping divs like so:

```
div.back {
    background:url(brick.png);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:right top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:765px;
    z-index:200;
}
div.flash {
    margin-top:-765px;
    z-index:201;
}
```

what i need to do is set the 'back' div offscreen for a time and then move it back.  i tried moving it using a bunch of different jquery methods but for some reason they move ***all*** of the divs instead of the one with the specified id.

so how do i move just the bottom one offscreen without affecting the top one?  it doesn't need to be animated at all; i just need it set aside until needed. (and "hide" won't work because it messes up my flash, so omit that from your suggestions if you don't mind.  :)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up solving it; instead of trying to move the topmost div i changed the code to alter the margin-top property of the lowest div instead of the highest one; that was able to leave the highest level one onscreen.  i still don't know why attempting to change margin-top of the topmost div would affect all the others but it seems to.

Answer (score 1):

would `$("div.back").hide()` do the trick?

Comment: that's why i said omit suggestions that include 'hide' -- it messes up the flash so it won't work.  i need to move it.

Comment: sorry... I guess you can either play with visibility css property (it's like display:none but keeps the layout) or use position:absolute; left: -2000px

Answer (score 0):

hide sets the display style to none if fx is off, otherwise it animates the opacity
you could try:

- disabling fx
- setting display to none by yourself
- setting visibility to hidden by yourself
- setting opacity to 0 with jquery
- setting position to absolute, left to -1000, top to -1000, width and height to 100 using jquery or by yourself
- putting the div somewhere else, and using remove and appendTo to move it using jquery (if it's just an image)

Comment: how would i set the position without jquery?  and why would i need to change the height?